# How do I get Unity camera frame in Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I am using an Android video chat SDK in Unity. I want to provide Unity camera frame to the SDK.
Now I set a RenderTexture to Camera.targetTexture, and I pass RenderTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr() to Android.
What should I do next? I googled many times, should I use GLES20 api? Or is there any other solutions?